# ORA-12504 При подключении через Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle в Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, oracle19c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке подключения к базе данных Oracle в Delphi через ADOconnection выдаёт следующую ошибку.
Версия Oracle 19c, instantclient 11.2.

Файл tnsnames.ora:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]